# Basic Header - Center - Footer Layout Vaadin

Tags: css, layout, vaadin, vaadin7

I've looked everywhere for an answer for this particular question, but found nothing useful. I'm trying to create a really simple layout in Vaadin that's common on many websites (including this one). I've included a diagram with this question. Basically need a footer to stay placed after the main section at all times, if the main section is large a scrollbar will appear and allow me to scroll to the bottom. If the content is small the footer will still come after the main section normally. If the browser window is small the Footer will NOT overlap the main section (this is where I'm stuck). I've tried so many approaches but nothing seems to work 100%... I would like to avoid messing with CSS files (if I can) and just use Java...
Thank you!

https://vaadin.com/documents/portlet_file_entry/10187/layout.JPG/7a978ae7-f926-472d-b1a1-d0aa3f2c3536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reworked my code and given up on the idea of using a tabsheet with dynamic content and a footer. Instead I'm using a simple menu and I've flattened my component hierarchy significantly, everything seems to work as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the BorderLayout addon.
It should do what you need,
just make sure put a correct component in the main part, so that scrollbars are shown when needed

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/borderlayout:vaadin

Comment: The problem was I didn't want the content section to expand indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

For example, (Note the comment in code, I dont know if you want an absolute or fixed layout)

```
public class BoxApp extends UI {

    HorizontalLayout head = new HorizontalLayout();
    Panel main = new Panel();
    HorizontalLayout footer = new HorizontalLayout();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        main.setStyleName(Reindeer.PANEL_LIGHT);
        head.addComponent(new Label("head"));
        main.setContent(new Label("<pre>MAIN START\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\n" + 
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" +
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMAIN END</pre>", ContentMode.HTML));
        footer.addComponent(new Label("footer"));

        VerticalLayout form = new VerticalLayout();
        form.setMargin(false);
        form.setSpacing(false);
        head.setHeight(50, Unit.PIXELS);
        form.addComponent(head);
        form.setExpandRatio(head, 0);
        main.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        form.addComponent(main);
        form.setExpandRatio(main, 10);
        footer.setHeight(50, Unit.PIXELS);
        form.addComponent(footer);
        form.setExpandRatio(footer, 0);
        // Drop following line if you don't want a fixed layout
        form.setSizeFull(); 

        this.setContent(form);
    }
}
```

Using the [JDAL](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/jdal-vaadin-ui-library) `BoxFormBuilder` (I wrote it) the syntax for building the root component is a little clearer

```
BoxFormBuilder fb = new BoxFormBuilder(); 
fb.setDefaultWidth(BoxFormBuilder.SIZE_FULL);
fb.row(50);                             // new row for head
fb.add(head);
fb.row(BoxFormBuilder.SIZE_FULL);       // new row for main, full height
fb.add(main);
fb.row(50);                             // new row for footer
fb.add(footer);

Component form = fb.getForm();          // Build the component.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my main problem was that main in my case was a HorizontalLayout before. Using main as a panel and adding a HorizontalLayout inside that panel worked great. Thank you :)

Comment: After testing this out a little more, it's not quite what I'm looking for (it's very close). I'm looking for something like this, http://www.templateaccess.com/demos/kaleidoscope-html/ simple table website. Right now if the main section is too large, I get a scrollbar for just that one section (and the footer is always at full size).

Comment: I have a tabsheet with components of variable size in the main section, what ends up happening is the tabsheet is drawn and the footer component ends up overlapping the tabsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I like using absolute positions for this.  Here is JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/upau942y/  You can use margin-top to create a gap between your footer and content of the website.

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>Thank you for viewing the site!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

Footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: JSFIDDLE is pretty cool :) ... So I'm forced to mess around with html and CSS ... no Vaadin specific way?

Comment: I don't know Vaadin, the code I wrote above is going to work on any framework and is very easy to implement.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok but that has to be rendered to html at one point or another, browsers do not read java, they read html.  So there has to be an option for custom html.

Comment: If I can't find a Vaadin specific way, I'll just do it like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
mainVLayout.setSizeFull();

mainVLayout.addComponent(headerComponent);
mainVLayout.addComponent(contentPanel);
mainVLayout.addComponent(footerComponent);

mainVLayout.setExpandRatio(contentPanel, 1);//this is the key.
```

Comment: Interesting, instead of having layouts you use components for all three sections. I'll give this a shot...

Comment: So this solution is almost there, the problem is that the contentPanel in this case can expand significantly so you end up with a lot of white space if you have a big screen and little content. But I guess this normal for ALL sites, I just need to add a lot of content...

Comment: It seems like I'm stuck... the big issue for me is that the contentPanel needs to hold a tabsheet with components that are variable in size. What ends up happening is the tabsheet ends up being populated and the footer overlaps the tabsheet instead of being added underneath.

Comment: Matt, can you post a screen-shot and the code snippets.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I reworked my code and gave up on the idea of using a tabsheet. Instead I'm using a simple menu and flattened my component hierarchy significantly, everything seems to work as expected now. Thank you however...

Comment: You are welocme Matt. I have been working on a web-app that has an accordion on LHS and a Tabbed RHS. If it helps, I can post the code snippets.